# How many boxes can we put to the big one?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to work on simple algorithms.

I have 600 snacks and I have two kind of boxes 45 snacks inside and 60 snacks. We need to receive all the amount of options that we can do with this small boxes

I have this kind of code, but some how it doesn't work in a right way.

```
k = 0
for x in range(0,601):
    for y in range(0, int(600 // 45) + 1):
        for z in range(0, int(600 // 60) +1):
          if x +45 * y + 45 * z == 600:
             print(x,'45=',y,'60=',z)
             k=k+1
print(k)
```

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  "It doesn't work" is not a problem specification.

Comment: "some how it doesn't work in a right way"—that's not a clear enough explanation. Please read [ask].

Comment: this is the intermediate result, that I sent previously. I'm stuck, that's why my code working on a half :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right it is simple math. You have 600 items and want use these 600 items in boxes size of 45 and size of 60. I don’t know what you use x for?

```
k=0
for y in range(0,20):
      for z in range(0,20):
          if 45 * y + 60 * z == 600
             print('45=',y,'60=',z)
             k = k + 1
print(k)
```

Result will be:

```
45= 0 60= 10
45= 4 60= 7
45= 8 60= 4
45= 12 60= 1
4
```

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance, z seems to represent the box that can hold 60 snacks. So the line of code `if x +45 * y + 45 * z == 600:` does not seem ok. The multiplication factor for z should be 60, i.e., `if x +45 * y + 60 * z == 600:`

Answer (score 0):

**The answer is** (*EDIT:* the solution is rewritten as functions):

- *Both functions return `list of tuples` with found combinations*.
- *Both functions `iterate` only throw one box size and filter by second one*.
- The `length` of the list that return both functions is the **amount of options**

  ```
  def box_comb(snacks, boxA, boxB):
      res = []

      for a in range(snacks // boxA + 1):  # Iterate by boxA
          free_space = snacks - boxA * a

          if free_space % boxB == 0:       # Filter by boxB
              b = free_space // boxB       # Calculate the count of boxB                    
              res.append((a, b))

      return res

  # Try this
  comb = box_comb(snacks=600,
                  boxA=60,
                  boxB=45)

  print(comb)
  print(f"Number of combinations = {len(comb)}")
  ```

**The output:**

```
[(1, 12), (4, 8), (7, 4), (10, 0)]
Number of combinations = 4
```

**Single line** solution:

*The same algorithm written as **single line** solution*

```
def box_comb_2(snacks, boxA, boxB):

    return [(a, (snacks - a * boxA) // boxB) for a in range(snacks // boxA + 1) \
            if (snacks - a * boxA) % boxB == 0]

# try this
comb = box_comb_2(snacks=600,
                boxA=60,
                boxB=45)

print(comb)
print(f"Number of combinations = {len(comb)}")
```

The output is

```
[(1, 12), (4, 8), (7, 4), (10, 0)]
Number of combinations = 4
```